# Gmail IMAP Javamail search returns no messages where web does

Tags: gmail, jakarta-mail, imap

I'm working on load testing a web application that sends links via email.  I have a gmail account set up specifically to be the recipient for this.  When generating new accounts I add a guid to the recipient email (eg. loadtest_**nmndbiwpdi**@gmaildomain.com).  When I execute the test it will either succeed entirely or fail entirely, but failures seem to be pretty random.

Here is my search snippet:

```
        if (!inbox.isOpen()) {
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        }

        SearchTerm toTerm = new RecipientTerm(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        messages = inbox.search(toTerm);
```

While the script is running, it executes this in a 100 iteration loop with a 3 second pause.  When it's failing script output with imap debugging on repeatedly shows the following:

```
A4 SEARCH TO loadtest_nmndbiwpdi@gmaildomain.com ALL
* SEARCH
A4 OK SEARCH completed (Success)
```

But no actual result.  during the period of execution, however, I can do a search in gmail for this recipient and it pops right up.  Any suggestions for getting to the bottom of this?

Comment: You could always use the Gmail specific search syntax, which should run the same search that Gmail does.  See the Gmail IMAP extensions.  I don't know if JavaMail supports it natively or not.

Comment: Hi Max, Thanks for the suggestion.  I switched to GmailRawSearchTerm and I'm seeing the same behavior.  I tried pop as well but the problem there is that the first time I load is pulls everything and seems to do a client side search, then subsequent searches return nothing.  This kinda leads me to believe that gmail is (quietly) encouraging me to not use them as a database, and that I should be caching all of the emails locally and searching there.

Comment: It's not that, it's that POP3 doesn't support remote search.  The protocol is very very very dumb.

Comment: Their IMAP server could just be buggy.  You could fetch all the envelopes yourself and do the search.  UIDs always increase, so you can always just look at the newest messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a local cache.  I initialize it at the beginning of the load test scenario, downloading the last days messages and capturing the last messages UID (using gmail imap plugin).  Any time a session looks for an email it looks in the local cache.  If it's not there it sets a flag so other sessions don't overlap caching and retrieves the newest messages.

Because it was intermittent, I wanted to give it a few days.  It's run perfectly for the past 4 days.  I could probably go one step better and set up a listener on the folder for new mail, but for now I'm satisfied that gmail was just returning 'success' but not doing the search after so many imap searches in succession.

Thanks to all for your feedback and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Gmail doesn't exactly implement the IMAP spec, especially for searching.  Gmail searches are always for whole words, although that shouldn't be a problem here.

You can try using the [Gmail-specific support in JavaMail](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/gimap/package-summary.html), e.g., the [GmailRawSearchTerm](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/gimap/GmailRawSearchTerm.html) class.